# Can "to become set" / "to become established" be translated to "fest werden" in German?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

Two native speakers of German did not like my use of "fest, nach" here, but I do not understand why.

> Individual goals for the training **are set** based on the patient's age and physical and mental abilities.

> Individuelle Ziele für das Training **werden fest**, nach dem Alter des Patienten und körperlichen und psychischen Fähigkeiten.

If I were to translate the German literally it would be,

> "Individual goals for the training **are established**, according to the age of the patient and the physical and mental abilities."

And that would seem to me a reasonable approximation to the original English. What is the problem?

Comment: Pro tip: Formulate your subject line in such a way that one does not have to reflex to close it with the following reason: "This question asks for the translation, proofreading, or spell checking of a text. It does not ask for help with a single issue within that text."

Comment: In your German version the main verb is *werden* and the *nach ...* attaches to that. So the literal translation is more like "Individual goals for the training become according to the age of the patient and the physical and mental abilities, fixed." This sounds wrong in English and I suspect that it's for about the same reason that the German version sounds wrong to German ears. The original English uses a specific verb "set" and you need to have something similar to it in the translation.

Comment: For a good  translation I miss more context. The sentence also seems to be targeted to a high-gloss flyer and (therefore?) has a lack of significant content as well: it just states, what  everybody would expect without thinking - perhaps with the exception of *mental abilities* (may be lack of imagination on my part concerning the kind of training).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

„Fest werden“ is not something a German would say in this context. It translates into „to become solid“...

> Beton wird fest, Eis in der Kühltruhe wird fest (wenn es vorher weich war), Butter wird im Kühlschrank fest.

Concrete becomes solid, icecream becomes solid in the fridge (if it was soft before), butter becomes solid in the cooler...

you get it...
What you wanted to say was „werden festgelegt“ or „werden definiert“:

> Individuelle Ziele für das Training werden festgelegt/definiert nach dem Alter des Patienten und körperlichen und psychischen Fähigkeiten.

Or -a little less clumsy-:

> Individuelle Ziele für das Training werden nach dem Alter des Patienten und körperlichen und psychischen Fähigkeiten festgelegt/definiert.

Comment: _je nach_ für Dein letztes Beispiel wäre noch klarer.

Answer (score 3):

Torsten Link's answer is perfect. Other German variants of the phrase "to set a goal" are

1. the literal translation "ein Ziel setzen"

or

2. "ein Ziel festsetzen"

My suggestion to translate the whole sentence is

> Die individuellen Trainingsziele werden auf Grundlage des Alters sowie der körperlichen und geistigen Fähigkeiten des Patienten festgesetzt.

Comment: Oder festlegen, evtl. sogar feststellen, bzw. fixiert.

Comment: @userunknown Völlig richtig, ich wollte aber die Entsprechung von *set* und *setzen* aufzeigen.